# Nginx & Passenger user permissions. Best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, rvm, passenger

I'm new to nginx, what's best practice for user/group permissions, when deploying (Ruby) application, using nginx and passenger?

Is better deploy as root or "deployer" user in some group? And how should I set folder/file permissions.

On Apache server I have /public /log and some other folders writible by www-data and user is root. This configuration doesn't work on nginx (for me).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use separate user per application and `Passenger`/`Nginx` should automatically use the directory owner to run the process, never use `root` user.

Comment: @mpapis Could u clarify your solution for "user per application"? I would like to know if rvm/rbenv is good to use in this case.